# make available selected date dependant on day of order

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an order form for my website. For the orders the requirement is 4 days clear notice(i.e. Monday for Friday, Tuesday for Saturday etc), but for orders made on a Saturday and Sunday the minimum day they can get is the following Thursday. They are also not allowed to select Sundays as a day for delivery.

This is my date field:

```
<p>What date is this required for?</p>
<p>Please note, we need 4 days clear notice(Monday-Friday)</p>
<input id="datefield" name="date" type='date' onkeydown="return false" min='2019-05-10' max='2000-13-13'></input>
```

This is the js I have so far for not letting them pick sundays and for making the earliest date selection 4 days in advance

```
<script>
var date = document.querySelector('[type=date]');

function noSundays(e){

    var day = new Date( e.target.value ).getUTCDay();

    // Days in JS range from 0-6 where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday

    if( day == 0 ){

        e.target.setCustomValidity('Unfortunately we cannot deliver cakes on a Sunday, please select another day');

    } else {

        e.target.setCustomValidity('');

    }

}

date.addEventListener('input',noSundays);

</script>

<script>

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate()+4;
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

</script>
```

So this is fine and works but how would I go about making a condition if the day they are ordering is a Saturday or Sunday that the minimum date they can select is the following Thursday?

Comment: I'm sure there is something elegant in moment.js or similar, but in plain JavaScript I can't think of anything better than repeatedly adding 1 day to 'today' and checking what day-number it is.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by doing the following:

```
   var today  = new Date();     // current date/time    
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

     if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 


    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    if (dd == "03" || dd =="04" || dd=="5" || dd=="06") {
    dd = today.getDate()+5;

     if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

    } 
     else {
      dd = today.getDate()+4;
     if(dd<10){
     dd='0'+dd
    }
    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);


    }
```

Might not be the best way but it works